# NSTableView first row initially appears behind the header

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa, nstableview, appkit

I am creating tableView in my application programmatically, and I have this problem:

Whenever the content size of my tableView is bigger than its frame, the **first row** of tableView appears under the header initially, **but it can be easily scrolled back into the position.**

The screenshots of what the window looks like after the **initial load**.

Content size bigger than tableView frame(the issue is here):

[image]

Content size smaller than tableView frame(all good here):

[image]

My NSViewController class code:

```
class MainViewController: NSViewController, NSTableViewDelegate, NSTableViewDataSource {

let label: NSTextField = {
    let label = NSTextField()
    label.stringValue = "Test App"
    label.font = NSFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 14)
    label.textColor = .white
    label.alignment = .center
    label.drawsBackground = false
    label.isBezeled = false
    label.isSelectable = true
    label.isEditable = false
    label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    return label
}()

let labelContainerView: NSView = {
    let view = NSView()
    view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    return view
}()

let tableView: NSTableView = {
    let tableView = NSTableView()
    tableView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    tableView.usesAlternatingRowBackgroundColors = true

    let column = NSTableColumn(identifier: .init(rawValue: "MyColumnID"))
    column.headerCell.title = "Test"
    column.headerCell.alignment = .center
    tableView.addTableColumn(column)

    return tableView
}()

let scrollView: NSScrollView = {
    let scrollView = NSScrollView()
    scrollView.hasVerticalScroller = true
    scrollView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    return scrollView
}()

override func loadView() {
    view = NSView()
    view.wantsLayer = true
}

var names: [String] = []

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    layoutUI()

    for i in 1...9 {
        let name = "Test \(i)"
        names.append(name)
    }

    scrollView.documentView = tableView

    tableView.delegate = self
    tableView.dataSource = self
}



func tableView(_ tableView: NSTableView, viewFor tableColumn: NSTableColumn?, row: Int) -> NSView? {

    let newCell = MyCellView(identfier: NSUserInterfaceItemIdentifier(rawValue: "MyColumnID"))

    newCell.textView.stringValue = names[row]

    return newCell
}


func numberOfRows(in tableView: NSTableView) -> Int {
    return names.count
}

func layoutUI() {
    view.addSubview(labelContainerView)
    view.addSubview(scrollView)
    labelContainerView.addSubview(label)

    NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
        labelContainerView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor),
        labelContainerView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor),
        labelContainerView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor),
        labelContainerView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.heightAnchor,
                                                   multiplier: 1/5),

        label.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: labelContainerView.centerXAnchor),
        label.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: labelContainerView.centerYAnchor,
                                       constant: -4),

        scrollView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.heightAnchor,
                                           multiplier: 4/5),
        scrollView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor),
        scrollView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor),
        scrollView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor)
        ])
}
```

}

Answer (score 2):

I would not recommend to setup a NSTableView in code. Its much easier to do this in Interface Builder and may prevent unwanted side effects. In any case if NSTableView is not displaying the first row as expected I would use scrollToVisible on the related NSScrollView to make the first row visible after loading the data.

Answer (score 2):

I've been working on the same problem (programmatically creating scrolling tables). I built a breadboard version, which worked except for this particular problem.

When an NSTableView has an NSTableHeaderView, the NSScrollview actually has TWO NSClipviews. The one accessed from the .contentView property contains the table view, the 2nd contains the header and an NSVisualEffectView. They are both subviews of the scroll view.

I got it to behave, that is, show the top row, by adjusting the contentView insets:

```
    scrollView.contentView.contentInsets = NSEdgeInsets(top: headerView!.frame.height, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: 0)
```

I tried various auto layout strategies, which didn't work, or seemed dubious.

Here is a trace of what it looks like for a two-column table filled with generated data to let me see what's going on.

Overview (not code, but the only way I could get it to format):

```
    Scroll View Subviews: 4
    NSClipView
      NSTableBackgroundView (-250.0, -456.0, 1000.0, 456.0)
      NSTableView (0.0, 0.0, 500.0, 4750.0)
    NSClipView
      NSVisualEffectView (0.0, 0.0, 500.0, 23.0)
      NSTableHeaderView (0.0, 0.0, 500.0, 23.0)
    NSScroller
    NSScroller
```

The two clip views, with their frame rects. 0 is the content view:

```
    ClipView 0 (0.0, 0.0, 500.0, 438.0)
      NSTableBackgroundView 0 (-250.0, -456.0, 1000.0, 456.0)
      NSTableView 1 (0.0, 0.0, 500.0, 4750.0)
    ClipView 1 (0.0, 0.0, 500.0, 23.0)
      NSVisualEffectView 0 (0.0, 0.0, 500.0, 23.0)
      NSTableHeaderView 1 (0.0, 0.0, 500.0, 23.0)
```

Still don't completely understand what's going on.

But I do believe that knowing how this stuff works under the hood, without IB magic, is a worthwhile exercise.

Answer (score 0):

I tried Ron's logical solution or using 'tableView.scrollToVisible(0)' after loading the data, but as annoying as this problem is, I was not able to keep the first row from hiding behind the headerView. Instead, I had to rely on an AutoLayout alternative to get this working and agree with Ron's comments about learning to do things programmatically.

Basically, since the NSScrollView's ("scrollView's") documentView will manage the view the scrollView scrolls within the contentView, after setting the scrollView's documentView to be equal to the tableView, you can (actually) set the topAnchor constraint of the scrollView's documentView (i.e., of the scrollable part of the tableView) to be below the tableView's headerView.

To do this, set the scrollView's documentView topAnchor constraint equal to the scrollView's topAnchor constraint and use a constant that adds the height of the tableView's headerView to the scrollView's topAnchor. This will position the scrollView's documentView (that shows the scrollable part of the tableView) below the tableView headerView (the tableView headerView defaults to the top within the scrollView).

See below methods (a 'layoutScrollView' method is included for reference, that would be called before the 'layoutDocumentViewInScrollView' method):

```
    func layoutDocumentViewInScrollView() {
        tableView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        scrollView.hasHorizontalScroller = false
        scrollView.hasVerticalScroller   = true

        scrollView.documentView = tableView
        
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            scrollView.documentView!.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.topAnchor, constant: tableView.headerView!.frame.height),
        ])
    }

    func layoutScrollView() {
        view.addSubView(scrollView)
        scrollView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            scrollView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.leadingAnchor, constant: 0),
            scrollView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.trailingAnchor, constant: 0),
            scrollView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.topAnchor, constant: 0),
            scrollView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.bottomAnchor, constant: 0),
        ])
    }
```